# Spring Boot One to Many Constructor composition

Tags: spring-boot, constructor, one-to-many

I have a question about the proper way to build constructors when performing a OnetoMany binding. My code as it stands works fine as far as I can tell, what I am actually asking is what is the preferred way to handle this situation, including being able to test it.

I have 2 classes with a OnetoMany relationship. The first class is as follows:

```
public class IAmTheOne
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "foreign_key_many")
   private Set<IAmMany> many;

   public IAMTheOne()
   {
      this.many = new HashSet<Many>();
   }
}
```

The second class is as follows:

```
public class IAmMany
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long id;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "foriegn_key_one")
   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
   private IAmTheOne one;

   public IAmMany(IAmTheOne one)
   {
      this.one = one;
      one.addMany(this);
   }
}
```

Is this the correct way to build the constructors for these two classes? Both seem to work fine without the setting of the other until testing where not having `this.many` initialized breaks my IAmTheOneService in some manner during testing.

Likewise testing my services for `IAmMany` breaks if I don't add the `one.addMany(this)` call and method to my classes.

Is this the correct way to set up the constructors using Spring Boot, or am I missing the proper way to test my services?

For testing I am setting up some dummy data to serve using Mockito when I mock out my repository. I think this is where I am running afoul of the lack of initialization, because while Spring Boot might initialize things for me, it does not happen when just constructing objects in my test.

Comment: So, your question is more on Junit testing side? May be a dumb question, but did you add code in constructor only to make your test work?

Comment: Yes, it also seems that David Wolff understood what I meant. The extra code in the constructors is not necessary for hibernate to build the objects, but it appears that hibernate isn't in the picture when testing the code using JUnit, so you have to have some backup mechanism in place if you wish to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that when Hibernate is not active you have to instantiate the objects required by your tests manually.  Whether you want to do that in a constructor is a different question entirely and will depend on your software requirements.

Most, if not all, of the `@OneToMany` examples in the Hibernate Reference pre-initialize the collection on the same line as the property definition.  For example: `private Set<IAmMany> many = new HashSet<>();`.  I don't think you can go wrong with that approach.

For the `IAmMany` class, your example is one way to manage the association between the objects, but once again how you manage them depends on your requirements.

If you haven't already, read the [Hibernate Reference regarding Bidirectional association management](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-capabilities). It may be helpful regarding what Hibernate does and does not do for you in these cases.  The link is as close as I could get you to the relevant part.  Search for "Example 307" to find it.

Comment: Thank you. I had considered that as another possibility on how to do it, but I generally have tried to steer clear of that in preference to instead have all of the initialization in one place in the constructor. I suppose there is a point to the existence of a pre-initialization value then.
Also I had noticed the example, and had built off of it, but I hadn't noticed the pre-initialization given in the example. A bit of oversight. Thanks for pointing it out!